# How can one apply and work for the Ethereum Foundation?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

I would like to know how one can apply and work for the Ethereum Foundation as a software developer. I tried to look online but could not find the answer.

Comment: I think you should contact one of the ethereum team. This kind of question is more suitable for reddit rather than stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

According to Vitalik's tweet 
https://twitter.com/vitalikbuterin/status/867355118005436416

> How you can help Ethereum: send smart people our way. Math, CS, dist sys, crypto, econ, game theory, behav econ all highly welcome.

And his reply:

> Researchers/devs working on foundation payroll part or full time is an option.

A lot of people submit their tweet-sized cvs in the thread. You could try it also!